# Mixing datasets in set ratio

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

In tensorlfow dataset, how do I mix 2 datasets, taking 75% of the set from my original data and 25% from the augmented data?

```
d = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("raw_data/")\
    .flat_map(tf.data.TFRecordDataset)
ad = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("augmented_data/")\
    .flat_map(tf.data.TFRecordDataset)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you can't use `len()` on a dataset object, so it's sometimes hard to know exact number of examples until you iterate a full epoch. But you can approximate this with `take` and `skip` methods.

```
train_dataset = dataset.take(number_examples_for_train)
test_dataset = dataset.skip(number_examples_for_train)
```

Those methods are a direct alternative to each other. 
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#take